# Make a copy of a board

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, copy

I am trying to make a board game, since every move has to be valid, so I am making a copy of board and make a move so I can verify if that move is valid or not.

First I initialize all the positions on the board to be 0 (**iterate through** the board and set every p to 0

```
 pair<int, int> p(y, x); 
 board_[p] = 0;
```

This is the copy board method

```
void Board::copy(Board & gb) {
for (int y = MIN_Y; y <= MAX_Y; ++y) {
    for (int x = MIN_X; x <= MAX_X; ++x) {
        pair<int, int> p(y, x); 
        if (gb.board_.at(p) != 0) {
            board_[p] = new Pieces(*gb.board_.at(p));  // **where I am confused**
        } else {
            board_[p] = 0;
        }   
    }
}
}
```

My container in Board is:

```
map<pair<int,int>, Pieces*> board_;
```

Now in a play method, I make a copy of the board

```
unsigned int play(Board & b){
   b.copy(*this);
}
```

My question: both

```
board_[p] = new Pieces(*gb.board_.at(p)); //Pieces is a class I defined
```

and

```
board_[p] = gb.board_.at(p);
```

compile without any errors or warnings. Which one should I use though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either may be correct, but you probably want the first one. The first will copy each of the `Pieces` over to the new board - this is known as a deep copy. The second will only copy the pointers to each `Pieces` over, so both boards point at the same set of `Pieces` - this is a shallow copy.

However, there is a bigger issue here. You are defining a `copy` function, but C++ gives us a language feature for doing this - copy constructors. You should instead define a function like so:

```
Board::Board(const Board& other_board) {
  // Copy everything from other_board to this board
}
```

And you would use it like so:

```
Board board;
Board newBoard(b);
```

Comment: In fact I had: Board::Board(Board & gb): board_() { 
 copy(gb);
}

Comment: Is it essentially a copy constructor?

Comment: @HoKy22 It should take a `const Board&` to be a copy constructor.

Comment: Why do I need the const? Looks it's working fine without const

Answer (score 1):

This is a *shallow* copy:

```
board_[p] = gb.board_.at(p);
```

This is a *deep* copy:

```
board_[p] = new Pieces(*gb.board_.at(p));
```

The first one only copies a pointer, so a change to a piece in `board_` will result in a change to the same piece in `gb.board_`. The second one actually copies the data, so changes are isolated.

Which to use depends on your application. If you want changes to propagate, then shallow copy. Otherwise, you'll need a deep copy.

It's worth noting that your code snippet makes it look like you are at risk for a serious memory leak. You are creating `new` pieces, but never `delete`-ing them.

Answer (score 0):

So, board_[p] can be a pointer to a Pieces ?

Then the first one is correct. the second one is the piece id number (not the pointer that you really intended to assign, from my understanding).

Answer (score 0):

Since you wouldn't like to modify the original, you need a deep copy. The second one is a shallow copy. So you will need the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The first would make a deep copy, i.e. copying the objects (cloning them), while the second would make a shallow copy, i.e. copying the pointers to the objects. In the later case you'd have to boards having references to the same instances of the `Piece` objects. The problem with this is that if one of the boards deletes the pieces, the other will point to dangling memory.